# Possible isometries of a positively curved $S^2\times S^2$

Tags: riemannian-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, isometries

Just to put things in perspective, recall that the Hopf Conjecture asks whether $S^2\times S^2$ admits a metric of positive sectional curvature. By the work of [Hsiang-Kleiner](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/journal-of-differential-geometry/volume-29/issue-3/On-the-topology-of-positively-curved-4-manifolds-with-symmetry/10.4310/jdg/1214443064.full), it is known that, if $S^2\times S^2$ admits such a metric, then its isometry group cannot contain a circle, and is hence finite.

> Q: If $S^2\times S^2$ admits a metric with $sec>0$, what is known about its isometry group $G$?

---

The only results I know of are:

0. [Edit suggested by Misha] The diagonal antipodal action of $\mathbb Z_2$ on $S^2\times S^2$, i.e., $\pm 1\cdot(x,y)=(\pm x,\pm y)$, cannot be isometric if $S^2\times S^2$ is equipped with a metric of positive curvature. By Weinstein's Thm, an orientation-preserving isometry of an even-dimensional positively curved manifold has a fixed point (and the antipodal map does not). Equivalently, it would induce a positively curved metric on the $2$-fold orientable cover of $\mathbb R P^2\times \mathbb R P^2$, hence on $\mathbb R P^2\times \mathbb R P^2$, but this contradicts Synge's Thm.
1. From [Wilking's thesis](https://web.archive.org/web/20050511004803/http://wwwmath.uni-muenster.de:80/u/weckerm/sfb/about/publ/wilking3.ps) (Prop 4.2), any simple subgroup of $G$ is either cyclic or isomorphic to a group in a finite list $F_1,\dots,F_k$ of simple groups. (This is actually true for any finitely generated subgroups of isometries of a manifold with $Ric≥0$).
2. From [Fang's paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0504504) (Thm 1.2), $G$ cannot have a subgroup of sufficiently large odd order (but this lower bound is huge, since it is estimated with Gromov's universal constant for the total Betti number).

---

Apart from these, are there other known restrictions on what $G$ can be like?

Comment: You should also include the classical result that $RP^2\times RP^2$ does not admit a metric of positive sectional curvature. This gives one more restriction for $S^2\times S^2$. 

Comment: @Misha: I believe there is, however, one little detail about using that $RP^2\times RP^2$ cannot have $sec>0$ to imply that the standard $Z_2\oplus Z_2$ action on $S^2\times S^2$ cannot be isometric w.r.t. a positively curved metric. By Weinstein's Theorem, any (orientation-preserving) isometry of a compact even-dimensional positively curved manifold always has a fixed point. Thus, the $Z_2\oplus Z_2$ action cannot be free on a positively curved $S^2\times S^2$, so the quotient wouldn't be $RP^2\times RP^2$, right?

Comment: That's right. The manifold $RP^2\times RP^2$ is, of course, non-orientable, but it has an orientable 2-fold cover, whose fundamental group acts on $S^2\times S^2$ freely preserving orientation. 

Comment: There must be some restrictions on smooth finite group actions on $S^2\times S^2$ regardless of curvature, e.g. groups that acts pseudo-freely are exactly those that cats linearly, see http://arxiv.org//abs/math/9906159, as shown by Michael McCooey who may tell you more on the subject.

Answer (score 8):

You should look at Andrew Hick's thesis,

Andrew Hicks, *Group actions and the topology of nonnegatively curved $4$-manifolds*, Illinois Journal of Mathematics. Volume 41, Issue 3 (1997), 421-437.

A corollary to his Theorem 2 shows that for a positively curved metric on $S^2\times S^2$ with $\delta$ pinching, the size of the isometry group is bounded above by a constant related to the pinching.

There are a few other interesting results about symmetries of nonnegatively curved 4-manifolds there.

Comment: @Luis: Thanks for the reference. I'm not sure I have read it before, I'll definitely check it out. By the way, welcome to MathOverflow -- it's great to see more differential geometers around here!